# How to find out the new language set by user?

Tags: android

My aplication needs to use device language even when it is running in background.

It currently listens to LOCALE_CHANGED broadcast event, but I don't how to get the language set by the user.

java.util.Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().toLowerCase() still returns the initial device language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that our application was listening to Local configchange, preventing Android doing the job when user changed language at the device level.

The solution was either handling onConfigurationChanged properly or stopping handling locale's configchange, so Android does the job and application language is changed automatically.

Thx for the help.